# Wireless headset won't work when plugged in and charging.

Tags: windows-8, usb, audio, bluetooth

I have a Plantronics headset with a mic. The bluetooth works fine and I set it as my default device, all that. But when the headset dies and I have to plug it into the USB port, no matter what playback device I select (even deactivating my speakers) there is no sound and the mic won't work. They seem to lose bluetooth connection when plugged in. The bluetooth symbol turns red and won't reconnect. It's not an issue of selecting the proper device in the Playback Devices window, since they work in every case except when plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Which headset are you using? Some headset will automatically turn off while charging so you can't pair it. It is better to look for the hardware spec first